# Unable to use devcontainers in VS Code under WSL

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I have a very minimal example:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── .devcontainer
│   └── devcontainer.json
└── README.md
$ cat .devcontainer/devcontainer.json 
{
        "name": "Test",
        "image": "alpine:latest"
}
```

When I open the folder and select "Reopen in Container". I get this error:

```
Stop (208 ms): Run: docker start 8d4a1484f7746e918f18f886da95d0803729ec19cd671bdd76b15307f2658a77
Error: Command failed: docker start 8d4a1484f7746e918f18f886da95d0803729ec19cd671bdd76b15307f2658a77
    at HR (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:2183)
    at tb (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:2121)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async QR (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:2006)
    at async cb (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:3110)
    at async i_ (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:13194)
    at async n_ (/home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:12950)
Stop (464 ms): Run in Host: /home/user/.vscode-server/bin/da76f93349a72022ca4670c1b84860304616aaa2/node /home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --workspace-folder /home/user/test-containers --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user\test-containers --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/user/test-containers/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
Exit code 1
Command failed: /home/user/.vscode-server/bin/da76f93349a72022ca4670c1b84860304616aaa2/node /home/user/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --workspace-folder /home/user/test-containers --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user\test-containers --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/user/test-containers/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
Exit code 1
Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e wslpath -u \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user\test-containers
Stop (57 ms): Run: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e wslpath -u \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user\test-containers
```

However, my Docker works in the terminal:

```
$ docker run -it alpine:latest echo "hello"
hello
```

I think this is a problem with WSL2, because the same example opened from Windows works.

Comment: If I change image to `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-12` it worked for me. I am doing it like this: 1. click button on bottom left and select "New WSL Window". 2. Open folder with devcontainer-spec. 3. Click the popup with "Reopen in Container". I had to rebuild the container once, and then everything worked.